# DjangoAdmin adding weird characters to ImageField

Tags: python, django

I have an ImageField for a "People" model..

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
    
    class People(models.Model):
        firstname   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        lastname    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        img         = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/people')
```

The problem is, when I try to add a people object through Django Admin, and I select an image file, Django admin adds weird characters (that looks like a hash value) at the end of the image, which causes the image to not appear on the website..

For example, this is my Django Admin page for adding people:

[image]

When I click save and check my admin, this is what appears:

[image]

As you can see, it added "_PQSSbcg" at the end of the image name for some reason.. Because of this, the website fails to display the image, because the template tries to find "jose_atria.jpg"..

Why is Django Admin adding this extra characters, and how do I get rid of this?

Thanks

Comment: Why is template looking for jose_atria.jpg? Can you show your template code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addition of the random extra characters is because you have uploaded files with same name twice.

Deleting the previous existing file before uploading it again will help you

Comment: Thanks. You're right that it is my second time uploading the image.. but  how do I delete an image file in the database using Django admin..?

Comment: Edit the object and in the image field, you will have a checkbox near the file name, with the link named `clear`. Use that :)

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner: In your view, you can check for file with the same name, using the `os` module of python, delete the file if you find it, and then save the new file.

Comment: found out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666309/replacing-a-file-while-uploading-in-django/31669165#31669165 thanks !